# How stop my slider when is focus by cursos

Tags: javascript, css

How can I stop my automatic slider when it is in focus by cursor and run again sliding automatically when out of focus?

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 4000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}

.text-uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.ff-serif {
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
}

.font-weight-normal {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.font-weight-medium {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.lts-1px {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.lts-2px {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.w-full {
  width: 100%;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.text-left {
  text-align: left;
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}

.d-block {
  display: block;
}

.d-inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}

.p-relative {
  position: relative;
}

.p-absolute {
  position: absolute
}

.bg-white {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.small {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

.card-heading {
  font-size: 2.25rem;
}

.styled-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #2196fe;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
}

.styled-link:hover,
.styled-link:focus,
.styled-link:active {
  color: #536dfe;
}

.shadow-1 {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.blue-hover {
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}

.blue-hover:hover {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  mar border: none;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #2196fe;
}

.clearfix::before,
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.float-left {
  float: left;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}


/**Margin and padding utilities*/

.mx-auto {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.ml-auto {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.mr-auto {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.mx-0 {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.mx-1 {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.mx-2 {
  margin-left: 2rem;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.mx-3 {
  margin-left: 3rem;
  margin-right: 3rem;
}

.my-0 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.my-1 {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.my-2 {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.my-3 {
  margin-top: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.mt-0 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.mt-1 {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.mt-2 {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.mt-3 {
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.mb-0 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.mb-1 {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.mb-2 {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.mb-3 {
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.ml-0 {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.ml-1 {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.ml-2 {
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.ml-3 {
  margin-left: 3rem;
}

.px-0 {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.px-1 {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

.px-2 {
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.px-3 {
  padding-left: 3rem;
  padding-right: 3rem;
}

.py-0 {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.py-1 {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.py-2 {
  padding-top: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.py-3 {
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
}

.pt-0 {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.pt-1 {
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.pt-2 {
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

.pt-3 {
  padding-top: 3rem;
}

.pb-0 {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.pb-1 {
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.pb-2 {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.pb-3 {
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="my-2 mx-auto p-relative bg-white shadow-1 blue-hover" style="width: 360px; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 1px;">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/442559/pexels-photo-442559.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" alt="Man with backpack" class="d-block w-full">

      <div class="px-2 py-2">
        <p class="mb-0 small font-weight-medium text-uppercase mb-1 text-muted lts-2px">
          gdfgdfgdf
        </p>

        <h1 class="ff-serif font-weight-normal text-black card-heading mt-0 mb-1" style="line-height: 1.25;">
          Planning your final summer trip
        </h1>

        <p class="mb-1">
          Summer is coming to a close just around the corner. But it's not too late to squeeze in another weekend trip &hellip;
        </p>

      </div>

      <a href="#0" class="text-uppercase d-inline-block font-weight-medium lts-2px ml-2 mb-2 text-center styled-link">
    Read More
  </a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="my-2 mx-auto p-relative bg-white shadow-1 blue-hover" style="width: 360px; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 1px;">
      <img src="https://www.backpackerguide.nz/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/new-zealand-1882703_1280.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" alt="Man with backpack" class="d-block w-full">

      <div class="px-2 py-2">
        <p class="mb-0 small font-weight-medium text-uppercase mb-1 text-muted lts-2px">
          hjuhkhjkhjkhj
        </p>

        <h1 class="ff-serif font-weight-normal text-black card-heading mt-0 mb-1" style="line-height: 1.25;">
          Planning your final summer trip
        </h1>

        <p class="mb-1">
          Summer is coming to a close just around the corner. But it's not too late to squeeze in another weekend trip &hellip;
        </p>

      </div>

      <a href="#0" class="text-uppercase d-inline-block font-weight-medium lts-2px ml-2 mb-2 text-center styled-link">
    Read More
  </a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="my-2 mx-auto p-relative bg-white shadow-1 blue-hover" style="width: 360px; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 1px;">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/01/13/01/36/bagan-1137015__340.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" alt="Man with backpack" class="d-block w-full">

      <div class="px-2 py-2">
        <p class="mb-0 small font-weight-medium text-uppercase mb-1 text-muted lts-2px">
          uuuuuu
        </p>

        <h1 class="ff-serif font-weight-normal text-black card-heading mt-0 mb-1" style="line-height: 1.25;">
          Planning your final summer trip
        </h1>

        <p class="mb-1">
          Summer is coming to a close just around the corner. But it's not too late to squeeze in another weekend trip &hellip;
        </p>

      </div>

      <a href="#0" class="text-uppercase d-inline-block font-weight-medium lts-2px ml-2 mb-2 text-center styled-link">
    Read More
  </a>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding event listeners to `mouseover` and `mouseout` on the container of your slides that clears/set your timeout, like this:

```
var slideIndex = 0;
var timeout;
var duration = 4000;

showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;

    var container = document.querySelector('.slideshow-container');
    var slides    = document.getElementsByClassName('mySlides');
    var dots      = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');

    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = 'none';
    }

    slideIndex++;

    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
    }

    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(' active', '');
    }

    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = 'block';
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += ' active';

    timeout = setTimeout(showSlides, duration);

    container.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        if (timeout) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = null;
        }
    });

    container.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
        if (!timeout) {
            timeout = setTimeout(showSlides, duration);
        }
    });
}
```